# $x\cdot \nabla u$ in polar coordinates?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, change-of-variable

I am solving a pde and one of the terms in the pde is $$x\cdot \nabla u=x\partial_x u + y\partial_y u.$$ I would like to write this term in polar coordinates.

Setting $x=r\cos\theta, y=r\sin \theta$, I know that,
$$\partial_x u = \cos\theta \partial_r  u - \frac{\sin\theta}{r}\partial_\theta u
$$
and
$$\partial_y u = \sin\theta \partial_r  u + \frac{\cos\theta}{r}\partial_\theta u
$$

which implies that
$$x\cdot \nabla u = r\partial_r u.$$

This seems wrong to me since it suggests that this term only depends on the radial component of the function $u.$ Did I make a mistake in my computation somewhere?

Comment: No, you didn't.

Answer (score 1):

There are not mistakes in your calculations. Since $x\cdot \nabla$ is the directional derivative in the radial direction, the result is not too surprising.